# Run a function a specified number of times

Tags: javascript

```
function runAgain()
{
    window.setTimeout(foo, 100);
}

function foo()
{
    //Do somthing
    runAgain();
}
```

I can use the above code to run a function infinite number of times with an interval of one second.

What is the standard way of running a function defined number of times. Lets say, I want `foo()` to be run 5 times with an interval of 1 second.

**EDIT** It's said that global variables should be avoided in Javascript. Isn't there a better way?

With input from answers, I created a function like this:  (Working Example: http://jsbin.com/upasem/edit#javascript,html )

```
var foo = function() {
    console.log(new Date().getTime());  
};


var handler = function(count) {
    var caller = arguments.callee;
    //Infinite
    if (count == -1) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            foo();
            caller(count);
        }, 1000);
    }
    if (count > 0) {
        if (count == 0) return;
        foo();
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            caller(count - 1);
        }, 100);    
    }
    if (count == null) {foo(); }
};

handler(-1); //Runs infinite number of times
handler(0); //Does nothing
handler(2); //Runs two times
handler(); //Runs foo() one time
```

Comment: Your example looks pretty OK to me. Just add a counter variable and you're done.

Comment: On avoiding globals: Aren't your functions global? What matter if you have a global counter too?

Comment: Check my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9859163/601179), the static variable looks cool to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have a function:

```
var foo = function() {
    ...
};
```

or if you prefer:

```
function foo() {
    ...
}
```

you could invoke it 5 times at intervals of 1 second like that:

```
(function(count) {
    if (count < 5) {
        // call the function.
        foo(); 

        // The currently executing function which is an anonymous function.
        var caller = arguments.callee; 
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            // the caller and the count variables are
            // captured in a closure as they are defined
            // in the outside scope.
            caller(count + 1);
        }, 1000);    
    }
})(0);
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T396B/).

Comment: I couldn't understand the (wholething)(0) part? What's happening here?

Comment: I am defining an anonymous function which calls itself recursively at regular intervals as long as the parameter is smaller than 5. The `(function() { ... })(0)` defines the function and invokes it immediately passing it 0 as argument.

Comment: **+1** Liked that, do you mind if I'll add comments to your code for newbies?

Comment: @Darin I added an example in question using your code. Thanks for the help. Correct me if I used anything wrongly.

Comment: I added comments. What do you think about the "static variable" version of mine?

Comment: @gdoron, the first comment you have put is not quite accurate. `foo` is not an anonymous function. It has a name and its name is `foo`.

Answer (score 10):

```
var counter = 1;
function foo()
{
    if (counter < 5){
        counter++
        window.setTimeout(foo, 1000);
    }
}

foo()// it will run 5 times;
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/G6KNQ/)

---

### Version with "static variable":

```
function foo() {
    if (typeof foo.counter == 'undefined') {
        foo.counter = 0;
    }
    alert("Run No. " + (++foo.counter));

    if (foo.counter < 5) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            foo(foo.counter + 1);
        }, 400);
    }    
}

foo();
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YDVt9/)

---

**Version with hidden input**

```
function foo() {
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    var counterValue = parseInt(counter.value, 10);
    alert('Run No. ' + counterValue);
    if (counterValue< 5) {
        counter.value = counterValue + 1;
        window.setTimeout(foo, 400);
    }
}

foo();​
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/G6KNQ/3/)**

---

**Version with closure :**

```
var x = function() {
    var counter = 1;

    (function foo() {
        alert('Run No. ' + counter);

        if (counter < 5) {
            counter++;
            setTimeout(foo, 400);
        }
    })();
};
x();​
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6KKQU/)

Comment: It will run four times because `counter` is only allowed to be `1, 2, 3, 4`.

Comment: @pimvdb. it runs **5** times. did you check the fiddle? the first run is done from outside the `foo` function. => 5 runs....

Comment: Isn't there a way without using a global variable?

Comment: `function foo(counter){counter-->0 && setTimeout(foo, 1000, counter);}foo(5);` - Non-global variable, works across all non-IE browsers.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood. I'm sorry.

Comment: @gdoron I am pretty new to javascript. Can you please point me to the right documentation/example?

Comment: @RobW. As a javascript master! What do you think is the best version from my updated answer?

Comment: @gdoron I'd vote for the last one, because it allows multiple instances of `x`. If the OP intends to use the method only once, the static method is also a good approach. The third one is the worst option, since it uses of an unnecessary DOM element.

Answer (score 2):

use a global variable and increment it in the function foo() to count the number of times it has been called.

```
var counter=0;
function runAgain()
{
    window.setTimeout(foo, 1000);
}

function foo()
{        
    //Do somthing
    if((++counter)<5)
    runAgain();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid polluting the global environment with additional variables, you can wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
(function() {
   var counter = 0;

   function foo() {
       // do stuff

       if ((++counter) < 5) window.setTimeout(foo, 1000);
   }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

`function call (func, arg) {
    return {
        func,
        arg,
        times: function (num) {
            let counter = 0;
            while (counter < num) {
                this.func(this.arg);
                counter += 1;
            }
        }
    };
}`

Then to use it, you can do

`call(yourFunction).times(10)`

or, if you need to enter an argument:

`call(yourFunction, arg).times(10)`